# Merge two arrays with Angularjs scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-resource

I have the following function for getting data by `$resourse`,I want to merge the output data with `$scope.data`.

`console.log(sasa) print`

```
[$promise: Promise, $resolved: false]
    Resource1:
    Resource2:
    Resource3: 
    Resource4: 
    Resource5:
    $promise: Promise
    $resolved: true
    length: 5
    __proto__: Array[0]
```

and `console.log($scope.data); print null`

```
$scope.data=[]
function getData(){
    var sasa= $resource('api/testrecordajaxs/:page/:size', {
            page : page,
            size : size
    }).query();
    $scope.data.push.apply($scope.data,sasa);
    console.log(sasa)
    console.log($scope.data);
    return $scope.data;
}
```

Comment: Were any of these answers helpful?

Answer (score 0):

You can use .concat to merge two arrays

$scope.mergedArray = $scope.data.concat(output );

Comment: could you make a plunker

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given enough information for me to be 100% sure, but it looks like you are trying to read all of the keys from an object, and not all the values of an array.  This is really what you need.

```
for (var key of Object.keys(sasa)) {
  $scope.data.push(sasa[key]);
}
```

The fix is down near the comment with "`THIS`" in all caps

```js
// $scope.data = []
var $scope =  { data: [] } // initialization just for this demo

//function getData(){
  //var sasa= $resource('api/testrecordajaxs/:page/:size', {
  //        page : page,
  //        size : size
  //}).query();

  // it looks to me like this isn't even an array in your example.
  var sasa = {
    Resource1: 1,
    Resource2: 2,
    Resource3: 3,
    Resource4: 4,
    Resource5: 5
  };
  
  //$scope.data.push.apply($scope.data,sasa);
  
  // THIS is what you want
  for (var key of Object.keys(sasa)) {
    $scope.data.push(sasa[key]);
  }
  
  console.log($scope.data);
//  return $scope.data;
//}
```